# How do I fade in a element if I have scrolled to a certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my example, I'm trying to fade in/out the element `overlay` if my window top position is about 100px from the bottom of it.

[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA4cz.gif)

How could this be done?

```css
.section-card{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #777;
}

.section-card:nth-child(2) {
    background: #666;
}

.section-card:nth-child(3) {
    background: #555;
}

.section-card:nth-child(4) {
    background: #444;
}

.section-card:nth-child(5) {
    background: #333;
}

.overlay{
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-card">
1
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
2
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
3
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
4
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
5
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement any JS?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve could be done like this.

```js
var overlays = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay');
var totalOverlays = overlays.length;
var overlayToChange = overlays[totalOverlays - 1];
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
 
var fromBottom = document.body.offsetHeight - (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY);
 
if(fromBottom <= 100){
 overlayToChange.style.opacity = 0.5;
 overlayToChange.style.visibility='visible'
}else{
 overlayToChange.style.opacity = 0;
  overlayToChange.visibility='hidden';
}

});
```

```css
.section-card{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #777;
}

.section-card:nth-child(2) {
    background: #666;
}

.section-card:nth-child(3) {
    background: #555;
}

.section-card:nth-child(4) {
    background: #444;
}

.section-card:nth-child(5) {
    background: #333;
}

.overlay{
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Overlays</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section-card">
1
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
2
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
3
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
4
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-card">
5
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```